# how do I overlay a bivariate distribution on top of a plot of samples?

Tags: r

If I have the following plot

```
plot(b, cex=.48, xlab = "x value", ylab="y value")
```

where b are data samples for a bivariate distribution

```
> head(b)
       [,1]       [,2]
[1,]  0.0000000  0.0000000
[2,] -2.3345703 -0.6655764
[3,] -0.8622095  0.2491481
[4,]  2.2643527  2.5498427
[5,]  1.0808216 -0.2335669
[6,]  2.0756586  0.9180297
```

how do I overly that plot with an analytical bivariate normal (from two normals with rho = 0.4?)

Comment: This might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28317203/r-superimposing-bivariate-normal-density-ellipses-on-scatter-plot

Comment: I'm not trying to put an ellipse around it, I want the actual distribution of the bivariate normal you would get if rho = 0.4. is there a d..norm function I can use to just overlay the analytical PDF..?

Comment: And what shape do you think that would be? I'm confused. Is there an example plot somewhere you are trying to imitate?